# Filtro em Select/Option dinâmicos

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select

```js
var escolas = ["UFSCAR", "USP"];
//var alunos = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
  escolas.forEach(function(item) {
    $('select.lista-escola').append('<option>' + item + '</option>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Escola: <select class="lista-escola" name="escola"></select> 
Aluno: <select class="lista-aluno" name="aluno"></select>
```

Vi algumas Perguntas que tratam o mesmo assunto, como essa: [Select Option com filtros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/213976/select-option-com-filtros)

Porém, o meu menu funciona de forma mais "dinâmica", ele é "populado" no próprio JS. E isso me deixou com mais dificuldade de modelar uma solução. 
Como posso fazer com que, quando selecionado a opção "UFSCAR", por exemplo, o `select` de alunos da escola respectiva seja mostrado?

Comment: Podes mostrar de onde vêm os dados dos alunos? Vais buscar esses dados remotamente ou são carregados com a página?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    escolas.forEach(function(item){
        $('select.lista-escola').append('<option>' + item + '</option>');
    });

    $('select.lista-escola').change(function(){
        var valueSelected = this.value;
        if(valueSelected=="UFRRJ"){
            alunosRural.forEach(function(item){
                $('select.lista-aluno').append('<option>' + item + '</option>');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Você pode usar o `change` para reconhecer quando o `select` é mudado, e então, é só adicionar um fluxo condicional e repetir o mesmo que você tinha feito para o `select` de alunos,